# Unable to include static package files in egg via setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, pyramid

I am trying out the Pyramid tutorial example and it's built-in setup.py file *appears* to be set up to add static files to the egg file but it doesn't actually happen. I've done some search and toying with the settings but I'm unable to get the desired behavior.

1. There is a MANIFEST.in file, it contains a line: `include *.ini`
2. `include_package_data` is set to `True`
3. `package_data` contains the entry: `{ '' : ['*.ini'] }'`

It doesn't seem to matter what setting I change, there appears to be no effect. I should probably mention the desired files are listed in the SOURCES.txt file.

The files I'd like to have included are in the root of the distribution's directory (where setup.py resides).

What do I seem to be missing here?

Comment: I think your `package_data` entry shouldn't be there if you set `include_package_data` - I'm not sure, but it could be that one option overrides the other.

Comment: I've tried a variety of combinations, but none seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 7):

The top level .ini files of pyramid are "non-package data files", i.e. there is no `__init__.py` in the directory they reside. This somehow means that they will not be included in the egg archive generated with `setup.py bdist_egg`, even if your conditions 1 and 2 are satisfied.

To include such "non-package data files", I think the cleanest way is to add them as `data_files` to `setup()`, e.g.

```
setup(
    ...
    data_files=[
        ('', [
            'development.ini',
            'production.ini',
        ]),
    ],
    zip_safe=False,
    ...
)
```

Then, the files will be included in the egg archive at the top level, retrievable with:

```
import os
import pkg_resources

dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('MyApp')
config_file = os.path.join(dist.location, 'production.ini')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's going on there, but if I do "setup.py sdist" on a freshly built Pyramid scaffold, this is where I get to.

Creating the project:

```
[chrism@thinko env26]$ bin/paster create -t pyramid_routesalchemy MyApp
Selected and implied templates:
  pyramid#pyramid_routesalchemy  pyramid SQLAlchemy project using url dispatch (no traversal)

Variables:
  egg:      MyApp
  package:  myapp
  project:  MyApp
Creating template pyramid_routesalchemy
Creating directory ./MyApp
  Recursing into +package+
    Creating ./MyApp/myapp/
    Copying __init__.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/myapp/__init__.py
    Copying models.py to ./MyApp/myapp/models.py
    Recursing into static
      Creating ./MyApp/myapp/static/
      Copying favicon.ico to ./MyApp/myapp/static/favicon.ico
      Copying footerbg.png to ./MyApp/myapp/static/footerbg.png
      Copying headerbg.png to ./MyApp/myapp/static/headerbg.png
      Copying ie6.css to ./MyApp/myapp/static/ie6.css
      Copying middlebg.png to ./MyApp/myapp/static/middlebg.png
      Copying pylons.css to ./MyApp/myapp/static/pylons.css
      Copying pyramid-small.png to ./MyApp/myapp/static/pyramid-small.png
      Copying pyramid.png to ./MyApp/myapp/static/pyramid.png
      Copying transparent.gif to ./MyApp/myapp/static/transparent.gif
    Recursing into templates
      Creating ./MyApp/myapp/templates/
      Copying mytemplate.pt_tmpl to ./MyApp/myapp/templates/mytemplate.pt
    Copying tests.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/myapp/tests.py
    Copying views.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/myapp/views.py
  Copying CHANGES.txt_tmpl to ./MyApp/CHANGES.txt
  Copying MANIFEST.in_tmpl to ./MyApp/MANIFEST.in
  Copying README.txt_tmpl to ./MyApp/README.txt
  Copying development.ini_tmpl to ./MyApp/development.ini
  Copying production.ini_tmpl to ./MyApp/production.ini
  Copying setup.cfg_tmpl to ./MyApp/setup.cfg
  Copying setup.py_tmpl to ./MyApp/setup.py
Welcome to Pyramid.  Sorry for the convenience.
Running /home/chrism/projects/pyramid/env26/bin/python setup.py egg_info
```

Running sdist:

```
[chrism@thinko env26]$ cd MyApp/
[chrism@thinko MyApp]$ ../bin/python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to MyApp.egg-info/requires.txt
writing MyApp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MyApp.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MyApp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to MyApp.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to MyApp.egg-info/requires.txt
writing MyApp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MyApp.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MyApp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to MyApp.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing paster_plugins to MyApp.egg-info/paster_plugins.txt
reading manifest file 'MyApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.rst'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'myapp'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'myapp'
warning: no files found matching '*.mak' under directory 'myapp'
w    arning: no files found matching '*.mako' under directory 'myapp'
warning: no files found matching '*.js' under directory 'myapp'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'myapp'
warning: no files found matching '*.xml' under directory 'myapp'
writing manifest file 'MyApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: missing required meta-data: url
warning: sdist: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) must be supplied
creating MyApp-0.0
creating MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
creating MyApp-0.0/myapp
creating MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
creating MyApp-0.0/myapp/templates
making hard links in MyApp-0.0...
hard linking CHANGES.txt -> MyApp-0.0
hard linking MANIFEST.in -> MyApp-0.0
hard linking README.txt -> MyApp-0.0
hard linking development.ini -> MyApp-0.0
hard linking production.ini -> MyApp-0.0
hard linking setup.cfg -> MyApp-0.0
hard linking setup.py -> MyApp-0.0
hard linking MyApp.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
hard linking MyApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
hard linking MyApp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
hard linking MyApp.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
hard linking MyApp.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
h    ard linking MyApp.egg-info/paster_plugins.txt -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
hard linking MyApp.egg-info/requires.txt -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
hard linking MyApp.egg-info/top_level.txt -> MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info
hard linking myapp/__init__.py -> MyApp-0.0/myapp
hard linking myapp/models.py -> MyApp-0.0/myapp
hard linking myapp/tests.py -> MyApp-0.0/myapp
hard linking myapp/views.py -> MyApp-0.0/myapp
hard linking myapp/static/favicon.ico -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/footerbg.png -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/headerbg.png -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/ie6.css -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/middlebg.png -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/pylons.css -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/pyramid-small.png -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/pyramid.png -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/static/transparent.gif -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/static
hard linking myapp/templates/mytemplate.pt -> MyApp-0.0/myapp/templates
copying setup.cfg -> MyApp-0.0
Writing MyApp-0.0/setup.cfg
creating dist
tar -cf dist/MyApp-0.0.tar MyApp-0.0
gzip -f9 dist/MyApp-0.0.tar
removing 'MyApp-0.0' (and everything under it)
```

The .ini files that were created in the scaffold are put into the resulting tarball:

```
[chrism@thinko MyApp]$ tar tvzf dist/MyApp-0.0.tar.gz 
drwxr-xr-x chrism/chrism     0 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  1162 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/setup.py
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism    16 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/README.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism    28 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/CHANGES.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  1457 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/production.ini
drwxr-xr-x chrism/chrism     0 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism     1 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/not-zip-safe
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   649 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism     6 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/top_level.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism    73 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/requires.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   514 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism     8 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/paster_plugins.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism    56 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/entry_points.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism     1 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/MyApp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   514 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/PKG-INFO
drwxr-xr-x chrism/chrism     0 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/myapp/
drwxr-xr-x chrism/chrism     0 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/myapp/templates/
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  3446 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/templates/mytemplate.pt
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   682 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/tests.py
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   237 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/views.py
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  1088 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/models.py
drwxr-xr-x chrism/chrism     0 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   203 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/headerbg.png
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  2797 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/middlebg.png
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism    49 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/transparent.gif
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism 33055 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/pyramid.png
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  4387 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/pylons.css
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  1406 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  7044 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/pyramid-small.png
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   758 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/ie6.css
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   333 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/static/footerbg.png
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   616 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/myapp/__init__.py
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   533 2011-07-28 16:08 MyApp-0.0/setup.cfg
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism  1123 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/development.ini
-rw-r--r-- chrism/chrism   128 2011-07-28 16:07 MyApp-0.0/MANIFEST.in
```

Comment: Yup, that is quite different then what I see. I'll try rebuilding it when I return. What version of Python, Pyramid, and setuptools are you using?

Comment: Pyramid 1.1, setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg, Python 2.6.

Comment: The .ini files get included with `setup.py sdist`, but not with `setup.py bdist_egg`